# Facing error with compiling opencv code

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv 2.4 and below is the code I am trying to compile.  I compile my code using this command

```
g++ -o "match" -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` match.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Why I am getting this error:

```
match.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
match.cpp:18:37: error: expected type-specifier before ‘SurfFeatureDetector’
match.cpp:18:37: error: conversion from ‘int*’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector>’ requested
match.cpp:18:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘SurfFeatureDetector’
match.cpp:22:2: error: ‘SurfDescriptorExtractor’ was not declared in this scope
match.cpp:22:26: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘extractor’
match.cpp:26:2: error: ‘extractor’ was not declared in this scope
match.cpp:29:2: error: ‘BruteForceMatcher’ was not declared in this scope
match.cpp:29:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
match.cpp:29:32: error: ‘matcher’ was not declared in this scope
```

I think there is some issue with the version of opencv I am using because the same code runs fine on 2.2 version but I am not sure what it is. HELP !!

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    cout << argv[1] << endl << argv[2] << endl;
    Mat img1 = imread(argv[1] , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    Mat img2 = imread(argv[2] , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints2;
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> feature = new SurfFeatureDetector(2500);
    feature->detect(img1,keypoints1);
    feature->detect(img2,keypoints2);

    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

    Mat desc1 , desc2;

    extractor.compute(img1,keypoints1,desc1);
    extractor.compute(img2,keypoints2,desc2);

    BruteForceMatcher<L2<float> > matcher;

    vector<vector<DMatch> > matches1;
    vector<vector<DMatch> > matches2;
    vector<DMatch> symMatches;
    vector<DMatch> outMatches;

    matcher.knnMatch(desc1,desc2,matches1,2);
    matcher.knnMatch(desc2,desc1,matches2,2);

    int count_inliers = 0 , count_matches = 0;

    for(vector<vector<DMatch> >::const_iterator matIt1 = matches1.begin(); matIt1 != matches1.end(); ++matIt1){
        count_matches++;
        if(matIt1->size() < 2)
            continue;
        for(vector<vector<DMatch> >::const_iterator matIt2 = matches2.begin(); matIt2 != matches2.end(); ++matIt2){
            if(matIt2->size() < 2)
                continue;
            if((*matIt1)[0].queryIdx == (*matIt2)[0].trainIdx && (*matIt2)[0].queryIdx == (*matIt1)[0].trainIdx){
                count_inliers++;
                symMatches.push_back(DMatch((*matIt1)[0].queryIdx,(*matIt1)[0].trainIdx,(*matIt1)[0].distance));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    vector<Point2f> points1, points2;

    for(vector<DMatch>::const_iterator it = symMatches.begin(); it!=symMatches.end(); ++it){
        float x = keypoints1[it->queryIdx].pt.x;
        float y = keypoints1[it->queryIdx].pt.y;
        points1.push_back(Point2f(x,y));

        x = keypoints2[it->trainIdx].pt.x;
        y = keypoints2[it->trainIdx].pt.y;
        points2.push_back(Point2f(x,y));
    }

    vector<uchar> inliers(points1.size(),0);

    Mat fundamental;
    fundamental = findFundamentalMat(Mat(points2),Mat(points1),inliers,CV_FM_RANSAC,2,0.8);

    vector<uchar>::const_iterator itIn = inliers.begin();
    vector<DMatch>::const_iterator itM = symMatches.begin();
    for(;itIn!=inliers.end();++itIn,++itM){
        if(*itIn){
            outMatches.push_back(*itM);
        }
    }
    cout << count_inliers << endl;
    cout << count_matches << endl;
    cout << (float) count_inliers/(float) count_matches << endl;

    float diff = (float) count_inliers/(float) count_matches;
//  if(diff > 0.30){
//      cout << "Similar Images " << endl << "-----------------" << endl;
//      exit(1);
//  }

//  vector<uchar> inliers(points1.size(),0);
    Mat homography = findHomography(Mat(points2),Mat(points1),inliers,CV_RANSAC,1);

    vector<Point2f>::const_iterator itPts = points1.begin();
//  vector<uchar>::const_iterator itIn = inliers.begin();
/*  while(itPts != points1.end()){
        if(*itIn)
            circle(img1,*itPts,3,Scalar(255,255,255),2);
        ++itPts;
        ++itIn;
    }
    itPts = points2.begin();
    itIn = inliers.begin();
    while(itPts != points2.end()){
        if(*itIn)
            circle(img2,*itPts,3,Scalar(255,255,255),2);
        ++itPts;
        ++itIn;
    }
*/

    Mat result;

    warpPerspective(img2,result,homography,Size(2*img2.cols,img2.rows));
    Mat half(result,Rect(0,0,img1.cols,img1.rows));

    img1.copyTo(half);





    // Add results to image and save.
    char name[1000];

//    strcpy(name,"./surf/surf");
//    strcat(name,argv[1]);

    cv::Mat output1;
    cv::Mat output2;
    cv::drawKeypoints(img1, keypoints1, output1);
    cv::drawKeypoints(img2, keypoints2, output2);
    cv::imwrite("./surf/img11.png", img1);
    cv::imwrite("./surf/img21.png", img2);
    cv::imwrite("./surf/img31.png", result);
    cv::imwrite("./surf/tt.png", result);
    cv::imwrite("./surf/img41.png", half);
    cv::imwrite("./surf/img51.png", output1);
    cv::imwrite("./surf/img61.png", output2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `BruteForceMatcher` is now called

```
cv::BFMatcher
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#bfmatcher).

You can define a matcher like this:

```
DescriptorMatcher* hammingMatcher = new BFMatcher(NORM_HAMMING,false);
//or
DescriptorMatcher* hammingMatcher = new BFMatcher(NORM_L2,false);
```

---

**EDIT**

Also in this [sample](https://github.com/kikohs/freak/blob/master/demo/freak_demo.cpp) code you can see how to use the old-version matcher by including the header

```
#include "hammingseg.h"
```

Answer (score 5):

Read [this discussion](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/87559) for the SURF and SIFT detectors - they have been moved as non free.

Add also as dynamic libraries to link `libopencv_nonfree.so` and `libopencv_features2d.so`.

For the `BruteForceMatcher` it looks still an open problem but I am pretty sure is inside one of the `.so` and I hope they did change also the headers. If you find something about the `BruteForceMatcher` I would appreciate.

Comment: As you said you wanted info on BruteForceMatcher have a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12508289/744859).

Answer (score 3):

Including the following

```
#"opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#"opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#"opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#"opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp" (BruteForceMatcher is defined here!)
```

and linking against the following

```
#opencv_core.so
#opencv_flann.soo (if youre using the FLANN matcher)
#opencv_highgui.so
#opencv_features2d.so
#opencv_nonfree.so
```

seemed to do the trick for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to include the header file for SurfFeatureDetector

[Here](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/classcv_1_1_surf_feature_detector.html)'s the API, where they mention the following:

```
#include <features2d.hpp>
```

Instead of including the file with the entire path, include just the name and let the compiler arguments (-I) specify its path. This is much more portable.

And if its not defined there, then look for it.  In linux, you can do the following:

```
# find . -name "*.h*" | xargs grep SurfFeatureDetector | grep class
# find . -name "*.h*" | xargs grep BruteForceMatcher | grep class
```

This should get all the *.h and *.hpp files and grep for SurfFeatureDetector and for those results, grep for class.

Comment: I included the header file 
#include </usr/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp> 
 but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: ok, well dig around and look where its defined, because its not finding the class definition.

Comment: I ran the find command in /usr/include/ folder and it didn't find anything. btw I am not only missing SurfFeatureDetector, I am also missing BruteForceMatcher and I cannot find that as well.

Comment: Well, I don't know what's wrong with the find command you wrote, but when I looked inside /usr/include/features2d/features2d.hpp , i could see bot the classes. Now I am including this file as header but still I am getting the same error. Is there some linking error. Help plz.

Comment: @user1054333, do you still get the same compilation error, or is it different now?

Comment: @user1054333, I fixed the find command. It was only looking for *.h, but that header is *.hpp

Comment: :Yeah, both the classes are present in /usr/include/opencv2/features2d but I am still getting the same compilation error. I am not sure if my file is linked or not. I am including "/usr/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp" and as I am including the whole path, I don't think there is supposed to be some error like this.

Comment: For clarification, I am getting this result out of the find command
class CV_EXPORTS SurfFeatureDetector : public FeatureDetector
class CV_EXPORTS BruteForceMatcher : public DescriptorMatcher

Comment: @user1054333, Im not sure how much more I can help :( Even though it mentions `SurfFeatureDetector`, also check that you also have the right include for `Ptr`. In your past comments, you've given 2 different include paths: /usr/include/features2d/features2d.hpp and /usr/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp, make sure you have that correct. Also make sure you have the namespaces correct.

Answer (score 0):

Its realy simple:

```
//matching descriptors
cv::BFMatcher matcher(cv::NORM_L2, true);
std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptor1, descriptor2, matches);
```

With the flag setting true you already gets a cross-check.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>
```

Add this line, It will work as before.